# Average measure of intersection of a convex region with its translate

Tags: convex-geometry, convexity, convex-analysis, lebesgue-measure, integration

Let $\lambda$ denote the Lebesgue-measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $C\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a convex region.

My question is about 
$$f(C):=\int_{C} \lambda(C \cap (x + C) ) \mathrm{d} x.$$ 
How large can $f(C)$ be? Of course, there is the trivial bound $f(C)\leq \lambda(C)^2$ but I would expect more something like $f(C) = O( \lambda(C) )$ at least. This question has probably been answered somewhere, and I suspect that the following might be very well known: for regions $C$ of constant measure, the value of $f(C)$ is maximal if $C$ is an $n$-ball (or something similar). I couldn't find any useful references regarding this question. If someone could help me out with some reference, or even a simple solution, I would be very grateful.

Comment: $O(\lambda(C))$ estimate can not hold and it has not even physical meaning, since two expressions are homogeneous with different exponents.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Yes, you're right. I completely missed that. It would be nice to know what the extremal case looks like still.

Comment: For $C$ a circle, I calculate $f(C)/\lambda(C)^2=1-3\sqrt{3}/4\pi$, roughly 0.5865

Comment: For the ball in $R^n$, the corresponding formula seems to be $$\frac{\int_{0}^1 s^{n-1} V_n^{cap}(1,s/2)ds}{V_n^{cap}(1,0)/n}$$ where $V$ is as in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/162873/210229

Comment: Looks like the optimal shapes are balls centered at the origin. Indeed, for 3 intervals $I,J,K\subset\mathbb R$ of given lengths, the integral $\int_I|J\cap(x+K)|\,dx$ is maximized when $I,J,K$ are all centered at the origin, so the Steiner symmetrization should do the job. On the other hand, I can easily miss something at 3AM, so it would be nice if someone else could verify (or refute) this claim :-)

Comment: I think it's worth accepting the answer now!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The following proposition answers OP's question regarding the upper bound of $$\tau(C) \Doteq f(C)/\lambda^2(C).$$

Let $B_n$ be the closed Euclidean unit ball of $\mathbb{R^n}$ centred at $0$, that is $$B_n = \{ (x_1,\dots, x_n) \in \mathbb{R^n} \, \vert \,\, 
x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2 \le 1\},$$
and let $\tau_n = \tau(B_n)$.

> **Proposition.**
> The Euclidean unit ball $B_n \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ maximizes $\tau(C)$ among all convex subsets of finite and positive Lebesgue measure, i.e., $\tau(C) \le \tau_n$ holds for any such $C$.

Claim 3 below gives a way to compute efficiently $\tau_n$ for all $n > 0$.

The proof of the proposition follows Fedja's idea. The first part consists in proving that $\tau$ doesn't decrease after [Steiner symmetrization][2]. This is Claim 4 below. The second part uses [1, Theorem 7.1.10] showing that some Euclidean ball centred at $0$ can be obtained as the limit of Steiner symmetrizations of $C$ for any compact convex $C$ of positive Lebesgue measure (equivalently, with non-empty interior).

When $n = 1$, the result is slightly stronger.

> **Claim 1.** Let $C \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a convex subset of finite Lebesgue measure $\lambda(C) > 0$. Then $\tau(C) \le \frac{3}{4}$ and equality holds if and only if $C$ is centred at $0$.

So, the above claim settles OP's question when $n = 1$. Unsurprisingly, the result generalizes to $\mathbb{R}^n$ in the following way.

> **Claim 2.** Let $C \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a parallelotope of positive Lebesgue measure. Then $\tau(C) \le (\frac{3}{4})^n$ and equality holds if and only if $C$ is centred at $0$.

Computing the maximum $\tau_n$ of $\tau$ can be achieved via the formula

> **Claim 3.**  We have
> $$ \tau_n = \frac{3}{2} \frac{\int^{\pi/3}_0 \sin^n(\theta) d\theta}{\int^{\pi/2}_0 \sin^n(\theta) d\theta}.$$
> In particular, $\tau_1 = \frac{3}{4}, \, \tau_2 = 1 - \frac{3 \sqrt{3}}{4 \pi}, \tau_3 = \frac{15}{32}, \, \tau_4 = 1 - \frac{9 \sqrt{3}}{8 \pi},
> \tau_5 = \frac{159}{512}, \, \tau_6 = 1 - \frac{27 \sqrt{3}}{20 \pi}
> $.

The above formula can be rephrased as $\tau_n = \frac{3}{2}\frac{W_n'}{W_n}$ where $W_n$ is the $n$-th [Wallis' integral][3] and $W_n'$ is recursively defined by $W'_0 = \frac{\pi}{3}, \,W_1' = \frac{1}{2}$ and
$W_n' =  - \frac{1}{2n}(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})^{n - 1} + \frac{n - 1}{n}W'_{n - 2}$. The latter formula allows an efficient computation of $\tau_n$ for any $n > 0$. As $W_n' \le \frac{\pi}{3}(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})^n$ and $W_n \sim \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2n}}$, the sequence $(\tau_n)_n$ converges to $0$ exponentially fast (we have for instance $10^{-7} < \tau_{91} < 10^{-6}$).

Before proving the claims, let us state some obvious, but important, remarks.

**Remark 1.** Let $A \in GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ and $d \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Let $C$ be any subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then we have
$$f(AC) = \vert \det(A) \vert^2f(C), \quad f(C + d) = \int_C \lambda\left(C \cap (C + d + x) \right)d\lambda(x).$$

In particular the ratio $\tau(C)$ is $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$-invariant but it is **not invariant under translation**. Indeed, if $C$ is a convex subset of finite positive Lebesgue measure whose interior contains $0$, then the function $f_C(d): d \mapsto f(C + d)$ has a non-empty and bounded support.

The following tightly relates to OP's question.

> **Question.** Let $C \subset \mathbb{R}^n $ be a convex subset of finite positive Lebesgue measure. For which $d$ is $f_C(d)$ maximal?

The following relates $\tau$ to Steiner symmetrization.

> **Claim 4.** Let $C \subset \mathbb{R}^n $ be a convex subset of finite positive Lebesgue measure. Let $H =\{0\} \times \mathbb{R}^{n -1}$ and let $C' \Doteq \text{St}_H(C)$ be the [Steiner symmetrization][2] of $C$ with respect to $H$. Then we have $\tau(C) \le \tau(C')$.

We now turn to the proofs of the above claims.

> *Proof of Claim 1.* Because of Remark 1, we can restrict, without loss of generality,  to intervals of the form $[-1, 1] + d$ with $d \ge 0$.
> A direct computation yields
> $$
> f([-1, 1] + d) = \int_{-1}^1 (2 - \vert d + x \vert)^{+} dx = 
> \left\{\begin{array}{cc} 
> 3 -d^2 & \text{ if } 0 \le d \le 1, \\
> \frac{1}{2}(3 - d)^2 & \text{ if } 1 \le d \le 3, \\
> 0 & \text{ if } d \ge 3.
> \end{array}\right.
> $$ where $g^{+} \Doteq \max(g ,0)$ for $g$ a real-valued function. The result follows.

> *Proof of Claim 2.*
> By Remark 1, we can restrict to the convex sets of the form $C = [-1, 1]^n + d$ with $d = (d_1, \dots, d_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
> We have $f(C) =  \int_{[-1, 1]^n} (2 - \vert x_1 + d_1 \vert)^{+} \cdots (2 - \vert x_n + d_n\vert)^{+}dx_1 \cdots dx_n$. It follows from Claim 1, that $f(C) \le \int_{[-1, 1]^n} (2 - \vert x_1 \vert)^{+} \cdots (2 - \vert x_n \vert)^{+}dx_1 \cdots dx_n = 3^n$ and the inequality is strict whenever one of the $d_i$'s is not zero. The result follows.

We denote by $V_n(r)$ the Lebesgue measure of the Euclidean ball of radius $r \ge 0$, that is, $V_n(r) = r^n\frac{\pi^{\frac{n}{2}}}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2} + 1)}$, and let $\nu_n = V_n(1) = \lambda(B_n)$.
Given a real number $h$ such that $-1 \le h \le 1$, we denote by $B_n^{\text{cap}}(h)$ the *hyperspherical cap of height $h$ along $x_n$* , that is the set of points $x = (x_1, \dots, x_n) \in B_n$ such that $x_n \ge h$. We also set $V_n^{\text{cap}}(h) = \lambda(B_n^{\text{cap}}(h))$.

> *Proof of Claim 3.* By definition, we have $f(B_n) = \int_{B_n} \lambda(B_n \cap (B_n + x)) d\lambda(x) = 2 \int_{B_n} V_n^{\text{cap}}(\frac{\vert x \vert}{2}) d\lambda(x)$ where $\vert \cdot \vert$ stands for the Euclidean norm of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Changing to [$n$-dimensional spherical coordinates][4], we get
> $$f(B_n) = 2 \int_{D_n} V_n^{\text{cap}}(\frac{r}{2})r^{n - 1} \sin^{n - 2}(\phi_1)\sin^{n - 3}(\phi_2) \cdots \sin(\phi_{n - 1}) dr d\phi_1 d\phi_2 \cdots d \phi_{n - 1}$$ where $D_n = [0,2\pi] \times [0, \pi] \times \cdots \times [0, \pi] \times [0, 1]$.
> Using the classical computation of $\nu_n = \lambda(B_n)$, we deduce that
> $$f(B_n) = 2n\nu_n \int_{[0, 1]} V_n^{\text{cap}}(\frac{r}{2})r^{n - 1}dr
> = 2^{n + 1}n\nu_n \int_{[0, \frac{1}{2}]} V_n^{\text{cap}}(s)s^{n - 1}ds
> .$$ Since $V_n^{\text{cap}}(s) = \int_s^1 V_{n - 1}(\sqrt{1 - h^2})dh = 
> \nu_{n - 1} \int_0^{\text{arcos}(s)} \sin^n(\theta)d \theta$, we obtain $$f(B_n) = 2^{n + 1}n\nu_n \nu_{n - 1} \int_{[0, \frac{1}{2}]} J_n(\text{arcos}(s))s^{n - 1}ds$$ where $J_n(\phi) = \int_0^{\phi}\sin^n(\theta)d\theta$. Using the substitution $\theta = \text{arcos}(s)$, we get
> $$
> \begin{eqnarray}
> \frac{f(B_n)}{2^{n + 1}n\nu_n \nu_{n - 1}} &=&  \int_{[\frac{\pi}{3}, \frac{\pi}{2}]} J_n(\theta)\cos(\theta)^{n - 1} \sin(\theta)d\theta \\ 
> &=& \frac{[J_n(\theta) \cos^n(\theta)]^{\frac{\pi}{3}}_{\frac{\pi}{2}} + \int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{\frac{\pi}{3}} (\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta))^n d\theta}{n} \\
> &=& \frac{2J_n(\frac{\pi}{3}) + \int^{\pi}_{\frac{2\pi}{3}} \sin(\theta)^n d\theta}{2^{n + 1} n} \\
> &=& \frac{3J_n(\frac{\pi}{3})}{2^{n + 1} n}.
> \end{eqnarray}
> $$
> Now the result follows from the identity $\frac{\nu_{n - 1}}{\nu_n} = \frac{1}{2 W_n}$.

Claim 4 is a specialization of

> **Fedja's Lemma.** Let
> $$\mathcal{I}(C, D, E) \Doteq \int_C \lambda(D \cap (E + x)) d\lambda(x)$$ where $C$, $D$ and $E$ are convex subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ of positive finite Lebesgue measure. Then $\mathcal{I}(C, D, E) \le \mathcal{I}(C', D', E')$, where $X'$ denotes the Steiner symmetrization of $X$ with respect to $H = \{0\} \times \mathbb{R}^{n - 1}$.

The proof of Fedja's Lemma can be reduced to the case $n = 1$. The proof of the case $n = 1$ is eased off by

> **Lemma 1.** Let $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+} \cup \{0\}$ be an even non-negative function which is concave on its support and non-decreasing on the negative real numbers. Then we have
> $$\int_I g d\lambda \le \int_{I'} g d\lambda $$ for every convex subset $I$ of $\mathbb{R}$ where $I'$ is the closed interval of measure $\lambda(I)$ centred at $0$.

> *Proof of Lemma 1.* The non-negative number $\int_I g d\lambda$ is the area of convex subset $C(I) \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ located between the $x$-axis and the graph of $g$. By hypothesis, we have $C(I)' \subset C(I') = \int_{I'} g d\lambda$, where $C(I)'$ is Steiner symmetrization of $C(I)$ with respect to $H = \{0\} \times \mathbb{R}$. As $C(I)$ and $C(I)'$ have the same area, the result follows.

We are now in position to prove Fedja's Lemma.

> *Proof of Fedja's Lemma.*
> Let us assume first that $n = 1$.
> As $\mathcal{I}(C + x, D, E) = \mathcal{I}(C, D, E + x)$ and   $\mathcal{I}(C, D + x, E + x) = \mathcal{I}(C, D, E)$, we can assume, without loss of generality, that $C$ and $D$ are centred at zero.
> Let us write $E = E’ + \eta$ and let $g(x) \Doteq \lambda(D \cap (E' + x))$.
> Then we have
> $$
> g(x) = \left\lbrace \begin{array}{ccc}
> \min(d, e) & \text{ if } \vert x \vert \le \frac{ \vert d - e \vert }{2}, \\
> \frac{d + e}{2} - \vert x \vert & \text{ if } \frac{ \vert d - e \vert }{2} \le \vert x \vert \le \frac{d + e}{2}, \\
> 0 & \text{ if } \vert x \vert \ge \frac{d + e}{2},
> \end{array}\right.
> $$
> where $d = \lambda(D) > 0$ and $e = \lambda(E) > 0$.
> The function $g$ satisfies the hypothesis of Lemma $1$, thus $$
> \mathcal{I}(C, D, E) = \mathcal{I}(C + \eta, D, E’) = \int_{C + \eta} g(x) d\lambda(x) \le \int_{C} g(x) d\lambda(x) = \mathcal{I}(C, D, E’)$$ which proves the result for $n = 1$.
> Assume now that $n > 1$. We denote by $\lambda_{n - 1}$ the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^{n - 1}$ and we identify $H$ with $\mathbb{R}^{n - 1}$.
> For $\xi \in \mathbb{R^n}$, we write $\xi = (\xi_1, \zeta)$, with $\xi_1 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\zeta \in H$.
> Given $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\zeta \in H$, we set $A^{\zeta} \Doteq \{ \xi_1 \, \vert \, (\xi_1, \zeta) \in A\} \subset \mathbb{R}$. Let $x = (x_1, z) \in \mathbb{R} \times H$.
> Observe that $(A^{\zeta})’ = (A’)^{\zeta}$ and $(A + x)^{\zeta} = A^{\zeta - z} + x_1$.
> By the Fubini-Tonelli Theorem, we have
> $\lambda_n(D \cap (E + x)) = \int_H \lambda_1(D^{\zeta} \cap (E^{\zeta - z} + x_1)) d \lambda_{n - 1}(\zeta)$.
> We shall use the abbreviations  $dz = d \lambda_{n - 1}(z)$ and  $d\zeta = d \lambda_{n - 1}(\zeta)$.
> Using Fubini-Tonelli’s Theorem and the case $n = 1$, we obtain
> $$
> \begin{eqnarray}
> \mathcal{I}(C, D, E) & = & \int_{H^2}
> \mathcal{I}(C^{z}, D^{\zeta}, E^{\zeta - z})d\zeta dz \\
> & \le & \int_{H^2} \mathcal{I}((C’)^{z}, (D’)^{\zeta}, (E’)^{\zeta - z}) d\zeta  dz \\
> & = & \mathcal{I}(C’, D’, E’). 
> \end{eqnarray}
> $$

Eventually, we can prove the proposition.

> *Proposition's proof*. By [1, Theorem 7.1.10], there is a Euclidean ball $B$ centred at zero which is the limit in the Hausdorff distance topology of Steiner symmetrizations of $C$ with respect to linear hyperplanes. As $\lambda$, $f$ and hence $\tau$ are continuous with respect to the Hausdorff distance topology (we use that $C$ has non-empty interior), we have $\lambda(B) = \lambda(C) > 0$ and we infer from Claim 4 that $\tau(C) \le \tau(B)$. By Remark 1, we have $\tau(B) = \tau_n$, which completes the proof.

---

[1] S. G. Krantz, H. R. Parks, "The Geometry of Domains in Space", 1999.
[2]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetrization_methods
[3]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis%27_integrals
[4]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere

Comment: I'ved added a post which gives an analytic formula for $\tau_m$ in terms of incomplete beta function. I've also derived a exponential bound which is essentially tight.

Comment: It seems convexity is not used at all in the proof of "Fedja's Lemma", since in the 1D case, you don't need the sets to be intervals. Also, Fubini-Tonelli  still carries over $1 \rightarrow n$. So, I guess compactness + convexity of D and E can be weakened to demanding that $D$ and $E$ be measurable with finite volume. Then, the limitting argument needed to complete the proof of the ultimate result can be replaced with a weaker form of convergence: almost sure convergence to a ball, of Steiner symmetrizations w.r.t random hyperplanes https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00526-012-0493-4.

Comment: @dohmatob This is a very interesting remark, thank you. I'll check the details. (By the way, you didn't answer my question about tightness: what does "tight" mean for your?)

Comment: Fixed (see comment below). For my remark on Steiner symmetrization compact nonconvex sets, actually you get convergence in a nonprobabilistic sense. See **Theorem 1.1** of https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Aljosa_Volcic/publication/284076871_On_iterations_of_Steiner_symmetrizations/links/5e5e96e692851cefa1da8e0b/On-iterations-of-Steiner-symmetrizations.pdf

Answer (score 6):

*How about a short solution to a much general problem, and without convexity assumption (which turns out to  be really just a distraction here) ?*

---

So, more generally, for nonempty compact subsets $A$, $B$, and $C$ of $\mathbb R^n$, define $F(A,B,C)$ by

$$
F(A,B,C) := \int_{A}\lambda(B \cap (x + C))dx.
$$

> In particular, the OP's question is concerned with $f(C) := F(C,C,C)$.

We shall proceed in 3 short steps.

- **Step 1.** The first step in analyzing $F$ is to realize that we can rewrite it as $F(A,B,C) = G(1_A,1_B,1_C)$, where

\begin{align}
G(u,v,w) = \int_{\mathbb R^n}\int_{\mathbb R^n} u(x)w(x-y)v(y)\,dxdy.
\end{align}

- **Step 2.** Now, by the *Riez rearrangement inequality*, we know that
  $$
  G(u,v,w) \le G(u^\star,v^\star,w^\star), $$
  where $u^\star$ is the *Symmetric decreasing rearrangement* of the function $u$. On the other hand, it is clear that
  $$
  (1_A)^{\star} = 1_{K(A)},
  $$
  where $K(A)$ is the centered ball of same volume as $A$.
  We deduce that
  $$
  F(A,B,C) \le F(K(A),K(B),K(C)),
  $$

and in particular, $f(C) \le f(K(C))$. The solution to the OP's question then follows from computation for the ball, in the begining of the accepted answer https://mathoverflow.net/a/282941/78539.

Answer (score 2):

### Analytic formula and an exponential bound

For $r \in [0, 1]$, define $\tau_m(r) \in [0, 1]$ by
$$
\tau_m(r) := \frac{1}{\lambda(B_m(r))}\int_{B_m(r)} \frac{\lambda(B_m(1) \cap (B_m(1) + x))}{\lambda(B_m(1))}dx.
$$

The case $r=1$ has been analysed in accepted answer. Extending user @Matt's comment, one can establish that (for the core idea, [see this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3668374/168758))

$$
\begin{split}
\tau_m(r) &= \frac{1}{V_m^{cap}(r, 0)}\int_{0}^r ms^{m-1}V_m^{cap}(1, s/2)ds = \frac{1}{r^mV_m^{cap}(1, 0)}\int_{0}^r ms^{m-1}V_m^{cap}(1, s/2)ds\\
&= \frac{1}{V_m^{cap}(1, 0)}\int_{0}^1 ms^{m-1}V_m^{cap}(1, rs/2)ds,
\end{split}
$$

where $V_m(r; h)$ is the volume (i.e Lebesgue measure) of the half-lens $\{x \in B_m(r) \mid x_1 \ge h\}$.

---

> **Preamble.** *I propose to obtain an analytic formula for $\tau_m(r)$ in terms of special functions (mostly hypergeometric functions). We will also obtain a good upper bound for $\tau_m(r)$.*

The end result will be the following exponential decay of $\tau_m(r)$ as a function on the dimension $m$.

> **Theorem.** *For every $r \in [0, 1]$ and large integer $m$, we have the upper bound*
>   $$
> \begin{split}
> \tau_m(r) &\lesssim \exp\left(-\frac{mr^2}{8-r^2}\right) + \frac{r(1-r^2/4)^{m/2}}{\sqrt{m\pi}}\\
> &\lesssim \exp\left(-\frac{mr^2}{8}\right) + \frac{r(1-r^2/4)^{m/2}}{\sqrt{m\pi}}.
> \end{split}
> $$

[image]
*Proof.*
Now, it is a classical computation that for $h \ge 0$  we have $V_m^{cap}(1, h) = \frac{\lambda(B_{m - 1}(1))}{2}\beta_{1-h^2}\left(\frac{m+1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)$, where $\beta_x(a, b) := \int_0^x t^{a-1}(1-t)^{b-1}dt$ defines the incomplete beta function. In particular, 
$V_m^{cap}(1, 0) = \frac{\lambda(B_{m - 1}(1))}{2}\beta_{1}\left(\frac{m+1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)$.

Thus, integrating by parts, we get

$$
\begin{split}
V_m^{cap}(1,0)\tau_m(r) &= \int_{0}^1 ms^{m-1}V_m^{cap}(rs/2)ds = \int_{0}^1 \beta_{1-(rs)^2/4}\left(\frac{m+1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)ds^m\\
&= \left[s^m\beta_{1-(rs)^2/4}\left(\frac{m+1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)\right]_0^1 + r\int_0^1 s^m(1-(rs)^2/4)^{\frac{m-1}{2}}ds \\
&= \beta_{1-(r/2)^2}\left(\frac{m+1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right) + R_m,
\end{split}
\tag{1}
$$
where $R_m := r\int_0^1 s^m(1-(rs/2)^2)^{\frac{m-1}{2}}ds$. Now, consider the change of variable $s = 2\sqrt{t}$. This gives $s^m(1-s^2/4)^{(m-1)/2}ds=2^mt^{m/2}\cdot(1-t)^{(m-1)/2}\cdot t^{-1/2}dt = 2^mt^{(m-1)/2}(1-t)^{(m-1)/2}dt$. Thus,

$$
\begin{split}
R_m &= r\int_0^1 s^m(1-(rs)^2/4)^{\frac{m-1}{2}}ds = \frac{2^m}{r^m}\int_0^{(r/2)^2}t^{(m-1)/2}(1-t)^{(m-1)/2}dt\\
&=: \frac{2^m}{r^m}\beta_{(r/2)^2}\left(\frac{m+1}{2},\frac{m+1}{2}\right).
\end{split}
\tag{2}
$$

Combining (1) and (2) then gives the analytic formula,

> **Analytic formula.** *For any $r \in [0, 1]$ and positive integer $m$, it holds that*
>   $$
> \tau_m(r) = I_{1-(r/2)^2}\left(\frac{m+1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right) + \frac{(2/r)^m\beta_{(r/2)^2}\left(\frac{m+1}{2},\frac{m+1}{2}\right)}{\beta_1\left(\frac{m+1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)},
> $$
>   where $u \mapsto I_u(a, b) := \beta_u(a,b) / \beta_1(a, b)$ is the CDF of $(a,b)$-beta distribution.

**Bounding the first term.**
Let $\delta := (r/2)^2$ and $p = I_{1-\delta}((m+1)/2,1/2)$.
It is known since [Temme (1992)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/037704279290244R) that for $p \in (0, 1)$ and **large** $a > 0$, the solution of the equation $p = I(t; a,b)$ is given (approximately) by

$$
t=t_p(a, b) \approx e^{-(1/a)Q_{1-p}(\Gamma(b,1))}, \tag{4}
$$

where $Q_{1-p}(\Gamma(b,1))$ is the $1-p$ quantile of the unit-scale gamma distribution with shape parameter $b$. Now by standard concentration results (e.g see Boucheron et al. textbook),

$$
Q_{1-p}(\Gamma(b,1)) \le \log(1/p) + \sqrt{2b\log(1/p)}. \tag{5}
$$

In particular, for $a=(m+1)/2$ and $b=1/2$ we get

$$
Q_{1-p}(\Gamma(1/2,1)) \le \log(1/p) + \sqrt{\log(1/p)}. \tag{6}
$$

Putting (2), (4), and (6) together and using the basic inequality $1-e^{-z} \le 2z/(2+z)\;\forall z \ge 0$, we see that

$$
\begin{split}
\delta &= 1 - t_{p}\left((m+1)/2,1/2\right) \approx 1-e^{-\frac{2Q_{1-p}(\Gamma(1/2,1))}{m+1}} \le 1-e^{-\frac{2}{m+1}\left(\log\left(\frac{1}{p}\right) + \sqrt{\log\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)}\right)} \le \frac{2\alpha}{2+\alpha},
\end{split}
$$

where $\alpha = \frac{2}{m+1}(\log(1/p)+\sqrt{\log(1/p)})$. Thus, $\alpha \ge \delta/(1 - \delta/2)$, and [this wolfram-alpha query](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Reduce+%5B%7B%282%2Fm%29%28log%281%2Fp%29+%2B+sqrt%28log%281%2Fp%29%29%29+%3E%3D+delta+%2F+%281+-+delta+%2F+2%29%2C+delta+%3D+%28r%2F2%29%5E2%2C++0+%3C%3D+r++%3C+2%2C+0+%3C+p+%3C+1%2C+m+%3E%3D+1%7D%2C+p%5D) tells us that we must have $p \lesssim \exp(-mr^2/(8-r^2))$. Putting things together then gives

$$
\begin{split}
I_{1-(r/2)^2}((m+1)/2,1/2) = p \lesssim \exp(-mr^2/(8-r^2)) \le \exp(-mr^2/8).
\end{split}
$$

**Bounding the second term.** It is a well-known result that

$$
\beta_z(a,b) \equiv a^{-1}z^a{}_2F_1(a,1-b,a+1;z),
$$

where $z \mapsto {}_2F_1(u, v, w; z)$ is the hypergeometric function. Thus, one computes

$$
\begin{split}
(2/r)^m\beta_{(r/2)^2}\left(\frac{m+1}{2},\frac{m+1}{2}\right) &= \frac{r}{m+1}{}_2F_1\left(\frac{m+1}{2},\frac{1-m}{2},\frac{m+3}{2},\frac{r^2}{4}\right) \\
&= \frac{r}{m+1}{}_2F_1\left(\frac{1-m}{2},\frac{m+1}{2},\frac{m+3}{2},\frac{r^2}{4}\right)\\
&\approx \frac{r}{m+1}{}_2F_1\left(\frac{1-m}{2},\frac{m+1}{2},\frac{m+1}{2},\frac{r^2}{4}\right)\\
&= \frac{r}{m+1}(1-r^2/4)^{(m-1)/2},
\end{split}
$$

where we have used the powerful identity ${}_2F_1(u, v, v; z) \equiv (1 - z)^{-u}$.
On the other hand, Stirling's formula gives

$$
\beta_1\left(\frac{m+1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right) \approx \Gamma(1/2)\left(\frac{m+1}{2}\right)^{-1/2} = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{m+1}}.
$$

Thus,

$$
\frac{(2/r)^m\beta_{(r/2)^2}\left(\frac{m+1}{2},\frac{m+1}{2}\right)}{\beta_1\left(\frac{m+1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)} \approx \frac{r(1-(r/2)^2)^{(m-1)/2}}{\sqrt{\pi(m+1)}}
$$

Putting every together then completes the proof of the theorem. $\quad\quad\quad\Box$

Comment: @LucGuyot There were a bunch of typos in what I wrote, leading to the inconsistent inequalities you mentioned. Fixed. Let me know if you still have any trouble following.

Comment: I was hasty in simplifying (6) to $\ldots \le 2\log(1/p)$, which is only true for $p \le 1/e$. Actually, I can do without this simplification and still get the $\exp(-mr^2/(8-r^2))$ term of my bound. See update.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very careful in the calculations. I meant $1-e^{-z} \le 2z / (2+z)$ for all $z \ge 0$. Also, indeed the next inequalities were reversed. Everything should be  fine now. Thanks for spotting the errors.

Comment: Because you are not using the big-O nor the small-o notation, and because there are at least two approximations in your computations, I would expect a constant factor $C$ (as close to $1$ as one would desire) to appear on the right side of the theorem's inequality. You also claim that your upper bound is tight. In which sense? Consider $r = 1$. We have $e^{-1/7} \approx 0.8668 > 0.8660 \approx \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. So $(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})^m$ would be a better asymptotic upper bound of $\tau_m(1)$.

Comment: Ah, the $\le $ in my theorem was meant to be be implicitly read as $\lesssim$. I'll make it more explicit, if that helps. BTW, glad to know that my bounds match (upto within dust) the quantity you computed using a completely different strategy.

Comment: I mentioned $\tau_m(1)$ only to illustrate my point (I would have been delighted to see that your bound for $r = 1$ were tighter): Is there a mathematical meaning attached to the word "tight"? In some context, like computational complexity theory (see $\Omega$ here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) there is a rigorous definition of a tight bound. If there is a mathematical meaning, how do you conciliate the fact that one bound look tighter than a tight bound?.

Comment: Sure, I probably ran out of words when I first typed it. Changed to "good upper bound". The bound is good, in the sense that with a bit of work, it can be reverse, at the prize of introducing a $\mathcal O(\sqrt{m})$ factor before $e^{-m\epsilon^2/C}$, everything else kept the same.