# $\newcommand\v{\operatorname{vol}_d(C}$Compact subsets of $ℝ^d$ which maximize $\inf_{|v|\le1}\dfrac{\v\cap(v+C))}{\v)}$ for fixed $\v)$ and $>0$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, measure-concentration, geometric-probability, isoperimetric-problems

Let $\operatorname{vol}_d$ be the volume measure on $\mathbb R^d$ and let $B_d$ be the unit-ball. For $\varepsilon \ge 0$ and a compact subset $C$ of $\mathbb R^d$ with $\operatorname{vol}_d(C)>0$, define

$$
\beta_\varepsilon(C) := \inf_{v \in B_d} \frac{\operatorname{vol}_d(C \cap (\varepsilon v + C))}{\operatorname{vol}_d(C)},
$$
where $v + C := \{v + c \mid c \in C\}$. Note that it always holds that $\beta_0(C) = 1$.

> **Question.** *For fixed $\operatorname{vol}_d(C)$ and $\varepsilon > 0$, what choices for $C$ maximize $\beta_\varepsilon(C)$?*

My rough guess is that $\beta_\varepsilon$ is maximized for balls, but I'm not quite sure how to establish such a result. This is indeed the case when we require $C$ be convex, as established here https://mathoverflow.net/a/282941/78539 (thanks user J.G for reminding me!), with $\inf_v$ replace with $\mathbb E_v$.

---

Also, same question with $\beta_\varepsilon(C)$ replaced with (perhaps the more appriopriate quantity?) $\liminf_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} \dfrac{\beta_\varepsilon(C)-1}{\varepsilon}$.

Comment: Something is wrong here. Clearly, the $\sup$ is $1$, attained at $v=0$ (if $vol_d(C)>0$).

Comment: Indeed, typo. I meant "minimize ==> maximize", and "sup ==> inf".

Comment: Among convex sets, the answer seems to be yes for balls: the answer in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/282526/average-measure-of-intersection-of-a-convex-region-with-its-translate shows that balls maximize your quantity over convex sets with the $\inf$ replaced by an expectation. For balls, the expectation is the same as the inf/sup, while for general sets the inf lower bounds the expectation, establishing the claim. It's hard for me to imagine anything fundamentally changes for nonconvex sets, but not sure.

Comment: Indeed, the question is settled for convex sets, I forgot to state this, and I actually partipated in that thread a few years ago. I've updated the question to reflect this piecd of information.

Comment: @J.G Actually, it seems my question is settled by a remark of mine on the accepted answer here https://mathoverflow.net/a/282941/78539. Basically, Sterner symmetrization of any compact subset of $R^d$, w.r.t to a dense set of directions converges in Hausdorff distance to the ball of same volume as $C$. See Theorem 1.1 of  https://www.researchgate.net/publication/284076871_On_iterations_of_Steiner_symmetrizations The argument can then proceed as in proof of the convex case, and with $\inf_v$ replaced with $\mathbb E_v$. I'd be grateful if someone else can confirm this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can link directly to comments.  I think you [meant](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/415146/newcommand-v-operatornamevol-dccompact-subsets-of-%e2%84%9dd-which-maximize#comment1064878_415146) to refer to [this comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/282526/average-measure-of-intersection-of-a-convex-region-with-its-translate/282941#comment911470_282941).

Comment: @LSpice ok, sorry I misunderstood what you were saying. Thanks for the tip about linking comments (rather than entire post). Deleted my previous comment on this thread.

Comment: Followup to my second-to-the-last comment which actually solves the problem asked here https://mathoverflow.net/a/415754/78539 as a special case