# Is $\int_{-c}^c |A \cap (x + A)|\, dx$ maximized when the measurable subset $A \subseteq \mathbb R$ is an interval centered at the origin?

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, measure-theory, calculus-of-variations, geometric-probability

Let $A$ be a nonempty measurable subset of $\mathbb R$, with Lebesgue measure $|A|=1$, and let $c>0$. Define the scalar $I(A)$ by

$$
I(A) := \int_{-c}^c |A \cap (x + A)|\, dx,
$$
where $x+A := \{x + a \mid b \in A\}$.

> **Question.** *Under the constraint $|A| = 1$, is it true that $I(A)$ is maximized when $A$ is an interval centered at the origin, i.e $[-1/2,1/2]$ ?*

In the case where $A$ is restricted to an interval, then the answer to the question is affirmative, and has been provided here https://mathoverflow.net/a/282941/78539 (under the name "Fedja's lemma"). Unfortunately, the solution is somewhat complicate and I don't see how to modify it so that it applies without convexity (i.e non-interval sets).

Comment: (i) "a nonempty measurable subset**s**"? (ii) "respectively"? (iii) "centered at the origin"? $I(A)$ is shift-invariant. (iv) The answer at https://mathoverflow.net/a/282941/78539 is to a substantially different question. (v) Is your $c$ fixed? (vi) Overall, are you sure this **is** the question you really wanted to ask?

Comment: This is immediate from the Riesz rearrangement inequality, since $I(A) = \int_{\bf R} \int_{\bf R} 1_A(x) 1_A(x-y) 1_{[-c,c]}(y)\ dx dy$.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_rearrangement_inequality

Comment: @TerryTao Indeed, this solves the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Sorry for the typos. Fixed.

Comment: @dohmatob Feel free to give an answer to this question to close it off.  Incidentally you may be interested in some recent work on questions of this type in https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.13873 and https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.08731 .

Comment: @TerryTao Indeed, thanks for the references. Very useful.

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer:** *Upon recommendation (in the comments), this post is just to close off the question, since it has been completely answered in the comments.*

---

- Indeed, as observed by user @Terry Tao in the comments, the question has a simple affirmative answer via the [Riez rearrangment inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_rearrangement_inequality).
- Using this machinery, a more general question in $n$ dimensions  is answered here https://mathoverflow.net/a/415754/78539, and the answer to my original question (on the real line) follows as an immediate corollary.